# How to plot multiple plotyy on top of each other in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot multiple `plotyy`s on top of each other. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436739/plotting-multiple-series-in-matlab), it was mentioned that with a `plotyy`, one cannot just use `hold on`. The correct command is reported to be `hold(...,'on')`.

Consider following code:

```
figure(2)
subplot(1,2,1)

myT=0:1:10;
myY1=myT*2;
myY2=1./sin(myT);
[dummy,h1,h2]=plotyy(myT,myY1,myT,[myY2' 2*ones(length(myT),1)]);
    hold(dummy(1),'on')
    hold(dummy(2),'on')
    set(dummy(1),'ylim',[0 20]);
    set(dummy(2),'ylim',[0 5]);
    set(dummy(1),'Ycolor','k')
    set(dummy(2),'Ycolor','k')
    set(h1,'color','b');
    set(h2,'color','r');
```

Execute it once, and you get
[image]

Now replace following 2 lines:

```
myY1=myT*3;
myY2=1./cos(myT);
```

You get
[image]

It seems that only the blue curve and the horizontal red curve are held. The other red curve is not. Why is this and what can I do in order to hold all curves?

**EDIT**

The MWE that will yield the second figure:

```
figure(2)
subplot(1,2,1)

myT=0:1:10;
myY1=myT*2;
myY2=1./sin(myT);
[dummy,h1,h2]=plotyy(myT,myY1,myT,[myY2' 2*ones(length(myT),1)]);
    hold(dummy(1),'on')
    hold(dummy(2),'on')
    set(dummy(1),'ylim',[0 20]);
    set(dummy(2),'ylim',[0 5]);
    set(dummy(1),'Ycolor','k')
    set(dummy(2),'Ycolor','k')
    set(h1,'color','b');
    set(h2,'color','r');

%%

figure(2)
subplot(1,2,1)

myY1=myT*3;
myY2=1./cos(myT);
[dummy,h1,h2]=plotyy(myT,myY1,myT,[myY2' 2*ones(length(myT),1)]);
    hold(dummy(1),'on')
    hold(dummy(2),'on')
    set(dummy(1),'ylim',[0 20]);
    set(dummy(2),'ylim',[0 5]);
    set(dummy(1),'Ycolor','k')
    set(dummy(2),'Ycolor','k')
    set(h1,'color','b');
    set(h2,'color','r');
```

I think that there is some interference because the `hold` and `set` are repeated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in R2016a. Using [this code](https://gist.github.com/sco1/34ba73065a8087095a4bee0e3c6bed04) results with [this figure](http://i.imgur.com/bXtZN2J.png).

Comment: @excaza I used Matlab 2015b. I obtain exactly the same result as your figure if I execute your code. Excuse me for not being entirely clear in my question, I will edit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second axes object from your first `plotyy` call is deleted when you call `subplot`. Though this may seem strange, it is [documented behavior](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html#moreabout):

> If a new subplot axes overlaps an existing axes, then MATLAB deletes
>   the existing axes. To overlay a new axes on top of existing subplots,
>   use the axes command. For example, `subplot('Position',[.35 .35 .3 .3])`
>   deletes any underlying subplots, but `axes('Position',[.35 .35 .3 .3])`
>   positions a new axes in the middle of the figure without deleting any
>   underlying axes.

I would suggest creating multiple `axes` objects and positioning/stacking them manually rather than utilizing `plotyy`. An example of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634426/create-an-xy-plot-with-two-y-axis/28634655#28634655).